# Ошибка в использовании cin

Tags: c++

Пишу функцию на С++ (под Visual Studio 2013), прошу помочь где-то ошибка только начал изучать C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double coub(int num,double num2);
void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    int a, b;
    cout << "Введите числа: \n";
    cin >> a, b;
    cout << coub(a,b) << endl;
    cin.get(); cin.get();
}

double coub(int num,int num2) {
    return num+num2;
}
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке покажете или предпочитаете чтобы мы сами угадали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что вы имеете в виду следующее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

double coub( int num, double num2 );

int main() 
{
    std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN" );

    int a;
    double b;

    std::cout << "Введите числа: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    std::cout << coub( a, b ) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get(); std::cin.get();
}

double coub( int num, double num2 ) 
{
    return num + num2;
}
```

Что касается вашего кода, то объявление функции `coub` перед `main`и после `main` не соответствуют друг другу. Хотя MS VC++ разрешает для функции `main` указывать тип возвращаемого значения `void`, тем не менее такое объявление `main` не соответствует стандарту C++. Функция `main` должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения `int`. Кроме того вы неправильно вводите значения перменных `a` и `b`.
Данное предложение

```
cin >> a, b;
```

содержит выражение с оператором запятая и эквивалентно двум выражениям
`cin >> a` и `b`, то есть с переменной `b` ничего не произойдет.

Comment: Спасибо очень доходчиво объяснили и к тому же показали)

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю вы не разобрались в специфике использования символов "," и ">>"

Насколько помню, вместо `cin >> a, b` нужно писать `cin >> a >> b`

Comment: я только начинаю изучать, спасибо вам за помощь!